# How is an IP address assigned to a process in TCP?

Tags: networking, tcp, sockets, client-server

When TCP connection is established between two sockets, suppose that there are multiple NICs in the computer, so which IP address will the socket bind [ or - which IP address will be passes into bind() function ]to  before communication is established. Is it decided by the OS?

Basically I have several doubts:

1. Is the socket(), bind(), connect() function called by the OS? If yes then which IP address is passed in the bind() function in case there are multiple NICs in the machine?
   I know I might be wrong at some places, please correct me

Comment: most apps use the constant `INADDR_ANY` or leave the address unspecified, which connects the socket to all interfaces. It is common for server applications that create listening ports,  to let you to configure an interface or address(es). https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=functions-bind-bind-name-socket

Answer (score 0):

> Is the socket(), bind(), connect() function called by the OS?

They're not called *by* the OS – they're *part of* the OS, so they are called by the program.

> If yes then which IP address is passed in the bind() function in case there are multiple NICs in the machine?

Most programs don't specify any address.

- When programs call bind() to select a local port for accepting inbound connections, they can use the special values `[::]` (aka IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT) and `0.0.0.0` (aka INADDR_ANY) indicating that they will accept connections to *all* addresses (current and future) on all local NICs.
- When making outbound connections, programs usually do not call bind() *at all*, letting the OS decide both the local address and the local port.

  Each OS has slightly different logic for source address selection. (For example, starting with Windows 7/Srv2008, the OS will choose the numerically-lowest address from the outbound interface. In Linux, individual routing table entries can have a "preferred" source address to use if the program doesn't choose one.)

When programs *do* specify a local address, often it's selected by the user, not by the program. (For example, most services have a "listen address" setting in their configuration.)

Comment: Ok.
What about a listening process, when it calls the bind() function, who set the parameters?
The user ?

Comment: Depends on the program, but most services will have both parameters configurable by the user, and will use 0.0.0.0 or [::] as the default listening address unless configured otherwise.